# MorphMap is not working in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I am using Polymorphic relationship in my models and with polymorphic relations I want to use Moprph map. To implement the concept of morph map I wrote my own service provider and registered it in app.php. Everything is working fine except Morph map. Morphmap is not working even with AppServiceProvider. Please have a look on my code

Service Provider

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

class MorphServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  /**
   * Bootstrap services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function boot()
   {
      Relation::morphMap([
        'First' => FirstModel::class,
        'Second' => SecondModel::class,
        'Third' => ThirdModel::class
      ]);
     }

    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function register()
    {
       //
    }
   }
```

Comment: _"is not working"_ is not a problem description. Why not? What should happen? What happens instead? Why is that bad?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations, Check-in "Custom Polymorphic Types" section in doc they told us to use lowercase, But you use capitalize, you need to use lowercase like 'first','second'. Try it maybe it will work.

Comment: Thats what I want to ask as I am new to Laravel. I've followed all steps described to use MorphMap. But still something is missing thats why its not working.

Comment: Also, share your model relation code in your question.

Comment: In this doc they did not mentioned anywhere to use lowercase instead of capitalising letters. But still I followed your instruction and it still not working@MD lyasin Arafat

Comment: Could you share your model relationship code with us? Maybe your problem with any other things and what type of your you faced, also share you errors.

Comment: I've figured out the issue. I was using paths of models like 'App\FirstName' rather than using its classes like FirstName::Class. But my problem is not fixed yet as Its working alright if I add it in AppServiceProvider but it not works in a separate service provider. Although there is no problem in my model but I share its model too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this situation too. Finally I solved this problem by running artisan command:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

#### The Reason Why MorphMap is not working

**The new custom service is not loaded.** Check `bootstrap/cache/services.php` to see if the new ServiceProvider is in the array of `providers`

```
<?php return array (
  'providers' => 
   array (
    0 => 'Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthServiceProvider',
    1 => 'Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastServiceProvider',
    2 => 'Illuminate\\Bus\\BusServiceProvider',
    3 => 'Illuminate\\Cache\\CacheServiceProvider',
    4 => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    5 => 'Illuminate\\Cookie\\CookieServiceProvider',
    6 => 'Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseServiceProvider',
    7 => 'Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider',
    8 => 'Illuminate\\Filesystem\\FilesystemServiceProvider',
    //...
```

By default this file should update automatically after the `app.php` has been altered.

In my situation, I accidentally ran the command `php artisan config:cache` before. This prevent the `services.php` from updating.  Further Reference:

[Laravel Doc: Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#configuration-caching)

#### Why caching config would prevent `services.php` from updating

1. check `bootstrap/cache/config.php`, look inside what's in there. `providers` is part of application config
2. check `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel`

   protected $bootstrappers = [
       \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables::class,
       \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration::class,
       \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::class,
       \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades::class,
       \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders::class,
       \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders::class,
   ];
3. check `Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration`
4. check `Illuminate\Foundation\Application`, `registerConfiguredProviders`

Finally, I have to say that I am quite new to laravel. If I made some mistakes, let me know. Thank you.